# 301 permanent redirection for various depth

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use this code for R301 for 1 depth of category.For example I want redirect `http://sitesample.ltd/new/mynews` to `http://sitesample.ltd/new/`this is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^mynews/(.+)$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And I want remove depth 2 and 3 from url. For example redirect `http://sitesample.ltd/new/mynews/photo` to `http://sitesample.ltd/new/`.I try this but not work:

```
RewriteRule ^mynews/(.+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mynews/(.+)/(.+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Another try but no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^mynews/([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mynews/(.+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what you're trying to do ...

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation. I add more text to describe. @Croises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to do that:

```
mynews/xxxx -> http://sitesample.ltd/new/xxxx
mynews/yyyy/xxxx -> http://sitesample.ltd/new/xxxx
mynews/zzzz/yyyy/xxxx -> http://sitesample.ltd/new/xxxx
```

You can do that:

```
RewriteRule ^mynews/([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mynews/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mynews/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or only this:

```
RewriteRule ^mynews/(?:[^/]+/){0,2}([^/]+)/?$ http://sitesample.ltd/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```